# Using HTML tags in the Email body while composing a mail in VB.Net to be sent via Outlook

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook, html-email

I am sending an email through Outlook using VB.Net code.

The syntax for creating the body of the message is: `oMsg.Body="string here"`

However, the message I am sending is more like: `oMsg.Body="Dear" & <database value> & ", you need to pay up" & <database value>`

I would like to change the color of the line of text and so used `oMsg.HTMLBody`, as I had seen elsewhere that we can use HTML tags to format the text. When I used the `<font>` tag, it didn't even recognise it, but when I used `<br>` and `<p>`, it immediately recognised and applied the tags as well.

What could I be doing wrong? How can I apply the tag to include the database values as well? Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<font>` is deprecated. Use `style` attributes on your tags instead to style them different ways.